# Is there a way to enable the trackpad to be gesture only? 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, cursor

I'm looking for a way to set up the trackpad to be gesture only so that I can set up 1-3 finger gestures without the trackpad controlling the cursor.  My end goal is to use the trackpoint for cursor and trackpad for swapping workspaces and other gestures. So far I have been unable to find a way to enable a "gesture only" mode.